# Passing id of element but getting the element itself

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

[Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gizIq) is a sample of my problem and below is the same code
**HTML**

```
<button id='preview_btn'>Add</button>

<table id="point_tbl">
    
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var pointList = [];

function deletePoint(id) {
  console.log(id);     // should be string but turns out to be the tr element
    for (var i = 0; i < pointList.length; i++) {
        if (pointList[i].id == id) {
            pointList.splice(i, 1);
            document.getElementById(id).remove();
            document.getElementById(id + "item").remove();
        }
    }
}

function getTemplate(obj) {
    var id = obj.id + "item";
    var aa = obj.id;
    var row = "<tr id = '" + id + "'><td>" + obj.sn + "</td><td>" + obj.x + "</td><td>" + obj.y + "</td><td>" + obj.tx + "</td><td>" + obj.ty + "</td><td>" + obj.lbl + "</td><td><button  class='del_point' onclick = 'deletePoint("+id+");'>Delete</button></td></tr>";
    return row;
}

document.getElementById("preview_btn").onclick = function(event) {
var id =  getUniqueId();
    var obj = {sn: pointList.length, x: 10, y: 10, tx: "0.5", ty: "0.5", lbl: "", id: id};
    $('#point_tbl').append(getTemplate(obj));
    pointList.push(obj);
}

function getUniqueId() {
    if (!getUniqueId.idList) {
        getUniqueId.idList = [];
    }
    var id = "uniqueID" + Math.round(Math.random() * 1000 + 1);
    if (getUniqueId.idList.indexOf(id) != -1) {
        return getUniqueId();
    } else {
        getUniqueId.idList.push(id);
    }
    return id;
}
```

When the `Add` button is clicked a new row is added with a button.
On this newly added button the `deletePoint` function is bind using the `getTemplate` function. The `deletePoint` function accepts the id of the row (tr) created by `getTemplate` function.

I am logging the the passed parameter in the `deletePoint` function. I was expecting this to be the id(basically a string) of the row but it turns out to be the whole `tr` element.

Not able to rectify the problem, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that the generated code in the event handler is

```
deletePoint(someId)
```

instead of being

```
deletePoint("someId")
```

As most browsers create a variable in global scope for all elements having an id (the name of the variable being the id), you pass the element, not the string (in some browsers you would pass `undefined`).

**Immediate fix :** Change

```
onclick = 'deletePoint("+id+");'
```

to

```
onclick = 'deletePoint(\""+id+"\");'
```

**Better :** don't inline JS code in HTML to avoid those problems. For example give an id and data-attribute to your cell and later bind as you do with other elements.

Comment: Thanks, this works, but cannot understand the problem with the current way. Can you you please explain it to me?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your delete function to fix problem

```
function deletePoint(id) {
  id.remove();
}
```